# Need help prepending to $PATH

Tags: macos, path, zsh

I have a directory `$CTERDAMBIN` that I want to **prepend** (not append) to `$PATH`. I say prepend because I want some executables to have precedence over the system's default, particularly when I run `vim` I want my version of vim (placed in that folder) and not the one in `/usr/bin`.

Here's what I've put in my zshrc:

```
export CTERDAMBIN="$CTERDAMHOME/bin"

# ...

add2path() { 
  if [[ :$PATH: != *:$1:* ]]; then 
    if [[ $2 == "head" ]]; then  
      export PATH=$1:$PATH 
    else # implies $2 == "tail"  
      export PATH=$PATH:$1 
    fi 
  fi 
}

# ...

add2path $CTERDAMBIN head
```

I thought this should suffice to put `$CTERDAMBIN` at the start pf `$PATH`. However, when I log in to zsh, I find that `$PATH` is equal to this sequence:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Library/TeX/texbin
/usr/local/go/bin
/Users/sterdam/cterdam/bin
/opt/homebrew/bin
/opt/homebrew/sbin
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin
```

Where `$CTERDAMBIN` is the `/Users/sterdam/cterdam/bin` in the middle. Why doesn't it get added to the top? Is there something else going on after my zshrc runs each time I log in that prepended all those top entries in $PATH?

I am on zsh on macOS 11.4 with an Apple chip. My zshrc also starts tmux if not running already.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue on MacOS 11.6 with zsh. I need to prepend to the front of $PATH. The technique I've been using is: export PATH="/foo/bar:$PATH"

Comment: I suggest that you put a `setopt localoptions xtrace` into your function, invoke it, and see how it behaves.